# How to manage key-value pairs storage when the value can be of several different types?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, data-modeling

Let's say I've got n properties (pairs key-value) that are either dates, numbers or strings. Which data model is the most efficient to store them?

Here is a solution I thought about:

[image: Data model]

Each row of the `data` table must be able to be linked to *n* properties of several types.

The advantage of this solution is that if I want to add a new type, I just have to add two new tables (`label_xy` and `value_xy`) instead of modifying the structure of an existing table. But is this solution really the most convenient one?

How would you have done this?

Thanks `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used all of the scenarios:

1. the one you described (each data type in own table)
2. the one from Anthony's answer - with value only string casted to ither datatypes on demand
3. one table with several columns with distinct datatypes, of them only one is used in each record (rest of them are sparse columns)

From those solutions: 1. was joining hell, 2. is good if your data is mainly strings, 3. although a bit of space-over-consuming is by far the best and most efficient.

As for 3. I must explain that the table looks like this:

```
EntityID int,
TypeID int,
LabelID int,
ValueInt int,
ValueDecimal decimal(12,4),
ValueString nvarchar(max),
ValueDate datetime
```

(Although `LabelID` defined `TypeID` I used both for join-less-usage purposes.)

Comment: This solution is interesting, but the problem is that the database should be quite scalable so that adding another type won't be so much work. And in that case, I'll have to change the structure of the table by adding a new column for the new type, am I right?

Comment: Yes you would, but how many new types could you even consider? There is not so many of them. And you can always use large range type (i.e. int) to cover small range types (i.e. tinyint).

Comment: You're right. I just have to choose an exhaustive-enough list of types. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Please consider, that such solution will probably never be efficient enough compared to classic, normalized schemas. I.e. it is uneasy to define good index on that table.

Comment: By *classic, normalized schemas*, you mean the one I proposed for example?

Comment: No, I mean by neither of the three dynamic-column solutions. :]

Comment: I think that myself and Kuba are of the opinion that the fully normalised solution is an impractical way of storing name/value pairs. Most (to my knowledge) projects that require this capability use a single table.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the nature of the data. If you have millions of values and need strong typing then this might be one approach. However, as you mention, every new data type requires new tables.

If in reality you will only have a couple of thousand name value pairs, and the RANGE of data is fairly regular, i.e. numbers are ints, dates are 10 chars and strings are less than say 200 chars you could define all this in one table viz:

id int,
name varchar(50),
type int,
value varchar(200)
index(name)

The id is not required, but is good design.
The naming convention is up to you, can apply a unique constraint if necessary.
The type could be 1=int, 2=date, 3=string (others can easily be added later)
The value can be defined as per your max string.

This solution would favour simplicity over performance, but this will be decided by the requirements, the string datatype will be your wild card, it might make more sense to define it as "text".

Comment: So, you store the value of the pair in a string-serialized form, and cast it to its original type when using it, don't you?

Comment: Yes, as I would assume that you know the type as required, and wrap the call to the DB as something like `int maxSessions=NameValuePairs.getInt("WP_maxSessions")` or `String defaultGreeting=NameValuePairs.getString("WP_defaultGreeting")` As mentioned, it is a very simple implementation, and while it does require casting, it can accomodate new data types very easily, e.g. `getIPAddress`